# Why isnt Nokogiri grabbing data as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parsing, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to grab data from a webpage, I was under the impression that the following would grab the data and return is as an array? Instead I am getting one big string which is causing a few issues.

```
 home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams")
```

if i was to use

```
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").text
```

i could understand the data being returned as as string. Am i looking at this the wrong way?

I have even tried

```
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map(&:text)
```

but that seems to be returning a string aswell? If i was getting an array returned in the console it would be in array format yes?

If someone could try this in their console

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'


FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map(&:text)
#home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams")
puts home_team
```

and just confirm that the output is a string in both cases and what the difference between the two are. slightly lost at the mo

Thanks

Comment: instead of doing puts, try doing puts home_team.inspect.to_s

Comment: @PavelS 1) The result of `inspect` is always a string, so calling `to_s` on it is superflous. 2) If `puts` is passed an argument that is not a string, it always calls `to_s` on it, so it is now doubly superfluous :) _(And 3) `p foo` is equivalent to `puts foo.inspect`, but far less typing.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of white space in the data.  I get an array when I do this:

```
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|team| team.text.strip}
```

Comment: quick question, how do you know an array is being returned from the console, all i can see is a list of team names, though they are aligned to the left compared to the other methods I have tried

Comment: Add an .inspect to the end: `home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|team| team.text.strip}.inspect`  You'll see that it's an array (or use `.class`)

Comment: thanks Richard, another question then ( seems you helped with previous question) why when I save to the model it is only saving the first letter of each string

Comment: its ok realised a mistake my end, was putting .first on the end of team when saving to model, thanks for your help, working as expected now

Comment: @Richlewis Note that if you just type `home_team` into your console it will call `.inspect` on it automatically. Alternatively, you can use `p home_team` (which also calls `inspect`). Another tool at your disposal: `puts home_team.class`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an array. It's just that `puts` is doing a `to_s` on. Check this out:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map(&:text)
# home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams")
puts home_team.class
puts home_team.map(&:strip).inspect

#=> Array
#=> ["Everton", "Aston Villa", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Swansea", "Man Utd", "Sunderland", "Tottenham", "Chelsea", "Wigan", "Sunderland", "Arsenal", "Man City", "Swansea", "West Ham", "Wigan", "Everton", "Aston Villa", "Southampton", "Fulham", "Reading", "Chelsea", "Newcastle", "Norwich", "Stoke", "West Brom", "Liverpool", "Tottenham", "QPR", "Man Utd", "Newcastle", "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Everton", "Reading", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Chelsea", "Arsenal", "Fulham", "Norwich", "QPR", "Sunderland", "Swansea", "West Brom", "West Ham", "Tottenham", "Liverpool", "Man Utd", "Man City", "Aston Villa", "Chelsea", "Everton", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Wigan", "Newcastle", "Reading", "Arsenal", "Fulham", "Liverpool", "Man Utd", "Norwich", "QPR", "Sunderland", "Swansea", "Tottenham", "West Brom", "West Ham", "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Everton", "Fulham", "Man Utd", "Norwich", "QPR", "Reading", "Stoke", "Sunderland", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Swansea", "Tottenham", "West Brom", "West Ham", "Wigan"]
```